# How to create a list of pairs from 1d list(s)?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I've got two 1-dimensional lists

```
A = {1,2,3}
B = {a,b,c}
```

How do I

1. create a list of all pairs from list `A` such that the result looks like `{{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}`?
2. create a list of all pairs from lists `A` and `B` such that the result looks like `{{1,a},{1,b},{1,c},{2,a},{2,b},{2,c},{3,a},{3,b},{3,c}}`?

I would also need both options, one with no duplicates as above and one with duplicates, e.g. one where the result from case 1 also includes `{{2,1},{3,1},{3,2}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the great replies! I could have chosen any of them as the accepted answer..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Ad. 1**

ordering  not valid:

```
Subsets[A, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}
> ```

or with ordering

```
Permutations[A, {2}]
```

**Ad. 2**

```
Outer[List, A, B]
```

> ```
> {{{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, {{2, a}, {2, b}, {2, c}}, {{3, a}, {3, b}, {3, c}}}
> ```

or exactly

```
Outer[List, A, B] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> ```
>  {{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}, {2, a}, {2, b}, {2, c}, {3, a}, {3, b}, {3, c}}
> ```

Answer (score 14):

As to question 1

```
Subsets[A, {2}]
```

Gives

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}
```

As to question 2

```
Tuples[{A, B}]
```

Gives

```
{{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}, {2, a}, {2, b}, {2, c}, {3, a}, {3, b}, {3, 
  c}}
```

Question 1 with dupes:

```
Tuples[A, {2}]
```

Gives

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 
  3}}
```

You can see this also includes `{1, 1}`. If all you want is the same result as before but reversed, you can do `Join[#, Reverse/@#]&@Subsets[A, {2}]` or use `Permutations[A, {2}]`  @EliLansey suggested in his answer

Question 2 with duples, I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps `Tuples[{A, B}]~Join~Tuples[{B, A}]` (or, equivalently, `Join[#, Reverse/@#]&@Tuples[{A, B}]`) ?

Answer (score 13):

Here's an answer for a variant of question #2 for those who were looking for something slightly different, as I was.

The original question #2 is asking for a generalized outer product (matching up every element of the first list with every element of the second list), which is why Artes correctly gives `Outer[List, A, B]` as the solution. Here `List` is the operator to perform on each pair of elements.

This lead me to solve my own problem, which was to create a generalized inner product list (matching up the i-th element of the first list with the i-th element of the second list), which looks like `{{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}}`.

```
Inner[List, A, B, List]
```

gives

```
{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}
```

Here, `List` replaces both the multiplication and addition functions in the usual inner product.

This is useful if you have two lists for separate 1D histograms that you want to combine into a 2D histogram with `Histogram3D`.

Answer (score 6):

### Regarding question 1:

```
Permutations[A, {2}]
```

gives

```
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}} *)
```

For all possible combos, use:

```
Tuples[A, 2]
```

which gives

```
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} *)
```

### And, for question 2:

```
Outer[{#1, #2} &, A, B]
```

gives

```
(* {{{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}}, {{2, a}, {2, b}, {2, c}}, {{3, a}, {3, b}, {3, c}}} *)
```

If you want it unsorted:

```
Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, A, B], 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding question 2:

```
Distribute[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}, List]
```

gives

```
(* {{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}, {2, a}, {2, b}, {2, c}, {3, a}, {3, b}, {3, 
  c}} *)
```