# How to obtain input and output of a function as a pair?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I thought this was going to be simple. But, I just wanted to print the input and the output of a function as a pair. But, I can't find it. I found this on another questions and this works(this was done by paul:

[How to create a list of pairs from 1d list(s)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/how-to-create-a-list-of-pairs-from-1d-lists))

This lead me to solve my own problem, which was to create a generalized inner product list (matching up the i-th element of the first list with the i-th element of the second list), which looks like {{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}}.

```
Inner[List, A, B, List]
```

gives

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}
> ```

Here, List replaces both the multiplication and addition functions in the usual inner product.

But, I would think there would be an easier way. My goal was to have something like this:{(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)......} -> This is a list of pairs. Not a list of list.

Thank you.

Comment: How about Thread[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}]?

Comment: Or `Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}]`

Comment: Thread Works:Thread[{Range[1, m - 1], Table[ModularInverse[x, m], {x, 1, m - 1}]}].  Transpose works:Transpose[{Range[1, m - 1], 
  Table[ModularInverse[x, m], {x, 1, m - 1}]}]      My goal was to have something like this:{(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)......}

Comment: `{#, ModularInverse[#, m]} & /@ Range[1, m - 1]`?